# Fix the perpetual machine

Tags: word, wordplay, cipher, mechanical-puzzles

[image: perpetual_word_machine]

Look at this marvelous machine I found in an antique store.  My auntie who knows about antiquities tells me they would feed a ribbon between the gears, turn the crank, and it would imprint an endless stream of non-repeating words on the ribbon.  (Well, maybe not *endless*.  Obviously, it has to return to its initial state eventually.  But still, a lot!)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to try it yet because two of the teeth are worn out and the letters are illegible.  (See the bottom of the larger gear and the left side of the smaller gear.)

**Can you help me figure out which letters belongs on the worn teeth so that I can get them restored?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These gears

> form six-letter words. Right now, LUSTER and PACKED are near the intersection point.
>
>  They have 18 and 24 teeth. This means that each letter will only occupy a single position in its word, every time it appears. The letters on the right gear will be used three times each, and the letters on the left will be used four times each.

The words formed are:

> [image: gear words]
>  `SOCKET, LUSTER, PACKED, BUTTED, LO__ED, PANTED`
>  `ROCKET, PUTTER, SACKED, LUSTED, POC_ED, BATTED`
>  `LO_KET, PUNTER, RACKED, PUTTED, SOC_ED, LASTED`
>  `POCKET, BUTTER, LA_KED, PUNTED, ROC_ED, PATTED`
>
>  And it's clear from this that the missing letters are a **C** on the large gear and a **K** on the small one.
>
>  (Interestingly, half of the letters don't contribute to this at all - a parity constraint means that the odd words in each cycle don't interact with the even words. You could blank out half the teeth and you'd get the same words, just with longer spacing between them... so I think your antique salesman just combined two smaller versions of this machine together!)

Comment: "Your antique salesman just combined two smaller versions of this machine together!"  Ha ha, true!  The antique salesman quickly realized that the most general version of the problem (N teeth interacting with M teeth, where N and M are relatively prime, to produce a string of NM letters which can be parsed into words of varying length) was computationally intractable.  Constraining the problem to words of fixed length reduced the computational complexity considerably.  Words of length 6 seemed to work best.

Comment: While there is a complete 4x4 matrix of 6-letter words, it cannot be turned into gears because 4 and 4 are not relatively prime.  However, there are a couple of nice 4x3 matrixes.  Each on their own would make a workable but small puzzle.  So, why not combine them to make something bigger?