# Get some perspective on your troubles

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|       Y                                                |
|                                      O                 |
|                  U                                     |
|                                                        |
|            W                  H                 H    W |
|        O                                               |
|                  U                                     |
|                         L              L           L   |
|                       D                                |
|                                                        |
|                                    P                   |
|I                                                       |
|            C                                           |
|                                                      K |
|                                                        |
|       Y                                                |
|                                          M  O          |
|                  U                                     |
|      R                           R  R                  |
|                                           S            |
|                                                        |
|                  U                                     |
| F                                  P                   |
|                                                        |
|                     A                                  |
|                                                    G   |
|                          A                             |
|                                 I                      |
|         N                                    N         |
|                                                        |
|               T   T          T                 T    A  |
|                      N                                 |
|                            D                           |
|                                                        |
|                                             G          |
|                 O                                      |
|                                                        |
|                                       B                |
|    V                     A                             |
|            C                                           |
|                                                      K |
|                                                        |
|                           I                            |
|              N                                        N|
|                                           S            |
|I                                                       |
|                            D                           |
|   E E    E  E                  E        E        E     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin — You might enjoy these:    
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114771/fix-the-perpetual-machine    
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115401/seti-message-received    
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114615/labyrinth-of-stones    
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112231/escape-across-the-floorboards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this nice little visual puzzle is a quotation:

> *"If everyone went out and laid their problems on the lawn, you would pick yours up again and go back inside."*
>
>  I cannot find a definitive original source of this quote but it appears to be a variation on a quote attributed across the Internet to Regina Brett: "If we all threw our problems in a pile and saw everyone else's, we'd grab ours back." The sentiment is the same - the idea that you're not the only person who has troubles, and in actual fact some people have troubles you'd rather not have yourself... (an interesting *perspective*, you might say)

How do we find this? As the title suggests: it's a matter of perspective!

> After all, it depends from which side you view the puzzle...
>
>  First, read **across** the width of the puzzle, taking the **top letter in every column** to find the words: "IF EVERYONE WENT OUT AND LAID THEIR PROBLEMS ON THE LAWN". (As if you are viewing the puzzle from the top and can only see the first letter you come across in each column...)
>
>  Then read **down** the puzzle, taking the **rightmost letter in every row** to find the words: "YOU WOULD PICK YOURS UP AGAIN AND GO BACK INSIDE". (As if you are viewing the puzzle from the right and can only see the first letter you come across in each row...)
>
>  [image: Diagram to illustrate extraction method]

Pleasingly, from a design point of view:

> There's a nice amount of 'reuse' of letters that are used in both readings of the diagram, and the puzzle itself thematically bears the appearance of items scattered across a rectangular lawn too!

Comment: Excellent.  And thank you for emphasizing "perspective" in both senses: mathematical projection, and frame of mind.

Comment: Source of the quote is Father of SlowMagic who is long past and was unlikely to have read Regina Brett, but they both could have paraphrased it from an older, original source.

Comment: BTW, you are very perceptive, the intention was to create a structure with as much letter reuse as possible.

Comment: @SlowMagic That's a nice family connection to preserve in a puzzle. I'm glad I was able to do SlowMagic Sr justice :)